# Jedis pool for BinaryJedisCluster

Tags: redis, jedis

`BinaryJedis` is not thread-safe but it can be derived from `JedisPool` `getResource` which returns a type `Jedis`. Is `BinaryJedisCluster` thread-safe? If not, is there a connection pool which returns a type compatible with `BinaryJedisCluster`? I want to use `BinaryJedisCluster` in a multi-threaded environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BinaryJedisCluster` is thread-safe. It internally uses `JedisPool`.

Elaborately,

- `BinaryJedisCluster` uses `JedisClusterConnectionHandler`
- `JedisClusterConnectionHandler` uses `JedisClusterInfoCache`
- `JedisClusterInfoCache` uses `JedisPool`

So, `BinaryJedisCluster` is as safe as `JedisPool`.